# xml split in half

Tags: xml, xpath, mule

I want to split my below xml into two parts each containing two stream.Product of the 4 contained,Is there any way using xpath or xpath-node by which i can achieve that,i tried the expression:

```
/stream.PurchaseOrder/orderLine/products/stream.Product
```

it splits the products in 4 parts,Can any1 help me with the expression or some technique to achieve the requirement?

```
<stream.PurchaseOrder>
  <metaData>
    <supplierId>1001</supplierId>
    <supplier>Supplier1</supplier>
  </metaData>
  <orderLine>
    <manufacturer>Manufacturer-1993628836</manufacturer>
    <location>Location-1616142228</location>
    <products>
      <stream.Product>
        <productId>852693979</productId>
        <productName>ProductName-20</productName>
        <price>100</price>
        <model>Model413</model>
        <quantity>50</quantity>
      </stream.Product>
      <stream.Product>
        <productId>1111</productId>
        <productName>ProductName11</productName>
        <price>40</price>
        <model>Model12</model>
        <quantity>150</quantity>
      </stream.Product>
      <stream.Product>
        <productId>85</productId>
        <productName>ProductName3</productName>
        <price>10</price>
        <model>Model3</model>
        <quantity>5</quantity>
      </stream.Product>
      <stream.Product>
        <productId>11</productId>
        <productName>ProductName4</productName>
        <price>4</price>
        <model>Model4</model>
        <quantity>15</quantity>
      </stream.Product>
    </products>
  </orderLine>
</stream.PurchaseOrder>
```

Comment: what will be the condition to select stream.Product? Or is it always in halve? (so if you have 8 stream.Product nodes you want the first 4 and the last 4)

Comment: it will be like if i have 12 products so 3 batches of 4 products,not half

Comment: if u have something for half that will be fine too for now.but the previous comment requirement will be better.Thanks :)

Comment: This is elementary to do in XSLT. Are you interested in an XSLT solution?

Comment: Ya i'll be glad to know more,but i havent used xslt so newbee to it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `count(/stream.PurchaseOrder/orderLine/products/stream.Product)` to count the number of Product elements and then divide it by 2. Use the `round` function to round it, in case there is an uneven number of elements. Then use the `position()` function as shown below:

The first half:

```
/stream.PurchaseOrder/orderLine/products/stream.Product[position()<=round(count(/stream.PurchaseOrder/orderLine/products/stream.Product) div 2)]
```

The second half:

```
/stream.PurchaseOrder/orderLine/products/stream.Product[position()>round(count(/stream.PurchaseOrder/orderLine/products/stream.Product) div 2)]
```

Comment: actually i am using splitter in mule so what its doing is splitting at the position being found so its splitting in only one stream.Product node

Comment: Cant there be a single strategy to split the xml ?i am having problem with using multiple splitters as the source data doesnt remain same?